# Filtering a GROUP BY query

Tags: sparql

Firstly I should mention I am using C-SPARQL, which is used for stream reasoning so I have timestamps associated with triples. Below is a query which returns to me a subject and predicate, along with the latest timestamp (I hope) assigned to it using the timestamp function in C-SPARQL, I however wish for it to return the object value that is associated with this timestamp as well. Any Ideas? I tried to just stick ?o into the select clause, but this gives a NON-group key error.

```
"REGISTER QUERY StreamQuery AS "
                                    + "PREFIX ex: <http://localhost/default/tr069#> "
                                    + "PREFIX f: <http://larkc.eu/csparql/sparql/jena/ext#> "
                + "SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p (MAX(f:timestamp(?s,?p,?o)) AS ?ts)"
                + "FROM STREAM <http://localhost/default/tr069> [RANGE 5s STEP 1s] "
                + "WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . "
                                    + "} GROUP BY ?s ?p "
```

If I have not been clear enough please ask.

EDIT: After some fiddling, I seem to be getting what looks like a correct result, wouldn't mind hearing other peoples opinions on what I have done though.

```
"REGISTER QUERY StreamQuery AS "
                                    + "PREFIX ex: <http://localhost/default/tr069#> "
                                    + "PREFIX f: <http://larkc.eu/csparql/sparql/jena/ext#> "
                + "SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o "
                + "FROM STREAM <http://localhost/default/tr069> [RANGE 5s STEP 1s] "
                + "WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . "
                                    + "{SELECT ?s ?p (MAX(f:timestamp(?s,?p,?o)) AS ?ts) WHERE{?s ?p ?o} GROUP BY ?s ?p}"
                                    + " FILTER(f:timestamp(?s,?p,?o)=?ts) } "
```

Comment: This is very strange, because if you are able to use ?o for the timestamp function that means the the variable is bind... could be a bug on the c-sparql implementation?

Comment: hm I had thought that it let me use ?o in the timestamp function as it is surrounded by a MAX, if i remove the MAX a similar NON-Group key error is thrown.

Comment: I appear to have made some progress, and updated the post.